# How the creation of HTTPSession works when request is coming from webserver instead of web browser?

Tags: java, session, web-applications, tomcat, servlets

I have a very basic question how the creation of HTTPSession works.I know you folks will fire me on looking at this question as similar kind
of questions exist.But there is reasoning why i am asking this question Here it is :-

I know httpsession is unique to web browser and server creates it when we do HttpServletRequest.getSession first time.It will maintaintain the same session till we
close the browser. But i have little bit different scenario.I Have a web application on one tomcat instance say T1.On welcome page of this web application
i have provided two links on click of which takes me to same java servlet(S1)  of different web application hosted on another tomcat instance T2 (these two links
opens two seperate pop up windows). Now first i click the link1 and inspect the sessionId in S1 and find its value as 1678.  Now first i click the link2 and 
inspect the sessionId in S1 and find its value  again as 1678. **My question here is why i am getting the same session id for both the requests origintaing
from link1 and link2? what can i do to to get the different session for both of these requests?**

**What i tried after looking for possible solutions on net :-** On click of link1, in Servlet S1 , i copied session attributes, invalidate it and create  new one.
Say new session id is 8765 . Now i click the link2 and found the same session  in this request too. So  i further invalidate it and creates new one(say 
new session id is 4897). Ideally it should expire the first browser session (generated on click of link1). To verify it,i click anywhere on pop up 1 it does not get
expired but i see again last generated session id i.e 4897. I am not getting why it attaching the same session id with both pop up windows?

**Folks Thanks for your patience for taking your time out and read this long scenario?**

**Edit :-**

```
      Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies(); 
        if(cookies!=null) 
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) { 
         cookies[i].setMaxAge(0); 
         context.getResponse().getHttpServletResponse().addCookie(cookies[i]);
        } 

    HttpSession myAppSession = req.getSession();//line 1
```

Assume on click of link1 i get session id as 1234,then after click of link 2 also i get the same session id. As per my understanding, after executing the code above line 1 , i should get the different session id as i am setting the MaxAge as0 before getting the session. But its not happening?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*I think this is what you are looking for* :

By default **session tracking happens by cookies**. **WebServer sends the session id to the browser in the form of cookie**. And, the **browser send the cookie having session id for the subsequent requests**.

**How does the browser identifies which cookies to send for a link/request?**
It is based on the these parameters. If the **request matches these paramters the browser sends that particular cookie**:

1. **Domain:** The domain name to which the request is made. Verify in your case if the domain name is same for two instances
2. **Path:** If the path name is same. Web Server send the context root as the path ,  requests under same context root share cookies.
3. **Secure:** Server sends if the given cookie is secure or not. Meaning, if the cookie can be sent on non-secure channel.

These parameters will let the browser to send the cookies to the server. **And because the same cookie is sent for both the instances you are having. I think the session id is being shared**.

If the request propeties such as Request URI, domain and path(i.e, context root) are same between requests, there is no way to tell the browser to use different cookies.

**You have some options below:**

1. Use different domain names.
2. Use different context roots.
3. Have a LB in front of two nodes and redirect to the correct node based on Session id

Comment: Ramesh thanks for reply. After considering the cookie fact, t refactored the code but still it returns the same session id. See my Edit section in  original post

Comment: Can u tell what is the domain name of both the servers.

Comment: You should try accessing with different domain names.

Comment: why do u want to setMaxAge(0), you dont want cookies working?

Comment: server is same so domain name is also same i.e localhost.webapp 1 is accessed thru link http://localhost:8080/myWebApp/login.do and link1 and link2 hit the the url as http://localhost:8888/wiki/bin/view/Main/WebHome. how shud i go with different domainnames when server is same.Not sure? Setting the maxage as 0 so that earlier cookies gets deleted and it gives me new session id. i want cookies working but trying different ways so that get different session id any how.

Comment: If the request propeties such as Request URI, domain and path(i.e, context root) are same between requests, there is no way to tell the browser to use different cookies.

Comment: You have some options below: 1) Use different domain names. 2) Use different context roots. 3) Have a LB in front of two nodes and redirect to the correct node based on Session id.

Comment: You said Use different domain names, can you brief how can i do it. As i said both link1 and link 2 takes me to same class which is under same  context root  i.e wiki on tomcat T1 hosted on machine m1.Thats why bot link takes me to localhost:8888/wiki/bin/view/Main/WebHome.I think when you are saying different domain names. Does it mean instead of localhost use some other machine in case link2. Correct?

Comment: If the server supports virutal hosting , having different domains for the same machine , you can try that. 
O

Comment: Otherwise have 2 different machines.

Comment: I am unable to undestand your actual use case? can u please tell me why do u actually need two different sessions for the same application and the same link?

Comment: Actually parent window is different application and pop up window is coming from different application hosted on another tomcat instance. Here is the issue i set different request paramter for two different pop ups. when i click these two different links for two different pop ups,  i  see these parameters specific to
each popup and i set them as attributes in request. but on further activity on these pop ups i do not get these parameters which i desperately need.

Comment: i can not set them in session because if i set them they are visible to both pop ups as session is same and i do not have identifier where i can identify which
session attribute is for which request as class  MyAuthServiceImpl  is same. So i have to set them in  request specific to pop ups. Also i can not change
the source code of java servlet classes for these pop up as this is third party open source product.i just plugged in my class MyAuthServiceImpl(for which
ineed to mention its name in cfg file)

Comment: So i think this is what is happening in your case: you access link1 from T1 session1 gets created. You access link2 from T2 browser sends session1 but T2 creates session2 as session1 does not exist there. And the sesion1 at T1 is lost as sesion1 in browser was replaced by session2.