# Session creation difference between Struts 1 and Struts2?

Tags: java, session, struts2

I'm converting a Struts 1 application to Struts 2 and have come across a strange Session issue.

We use Apache rewrite rules to change the URL for /page to be /app/proj/page which works fine for both applications.  However, everytime we go to /page in the Struts 1 application we keep the same session (the same JSESSIONID for the path / is used) but in the Struts 2 application we get a new Session each time (a different JSESSIONID for the path /app is created each time).

I've done some searching in the Struts 2 documentation, on Google and on here but I can't find anything that indicates a difference in how Struts 1 and 2 handle sessions so I'm guessing its a configuration or Java Action change thats required.

As I'm a newcomer to Struts 2 I've obviously missed something so any pointers would be gratefully received.

Thanks,

Z

FOLLOWUP : I can't post my own answer yet, but we have resolved it and this is what I was going to post:

Thanks to everyone for their help. We have now managed to retain the session using the ProxyPassReverseCookiePath setting in Apache. This was detailed on StackOverflow here :

How to properly set JSESSIONID cookie path behind reverse proxy

and we implemented by putting :

ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /app2 /

in the apache httpd-vhosts.conf.

Thanks,

Z

Comment: Are you using url-rewriting for session tracking? I mean have you disabled cookies?

Comment: With the new Struts 2 and old Struts 1 applications deployed, all I am doing is changing where the rewrite rule goes to in Apache and restarting Apache so there is no change as far as that goes for cookie handling.

Comment: It's not very clear from your question. So I'll have to ask a few more questions: Are these pages authenticated pages and you looses session when you switch between pages or is it just a new jsessionId? Have you compared the headers for both the application when you go to /page?

Comment: Which AS are you using (for both S1 and S2 if they differ)?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  They aren't authenticated sessions, so its just a new jsessionId which isn't in itself a problem but might be when we come to convert other Struts1 applications in the future that do have authenticated sessions which is why I wanted to find out what was going on.  Having looked at the headers the only difference seems to be the Set-Cookie line which in the Struts1 response has the additional information of 'Version=1; Comment=Sun+ONE+Application+Server+Session+Tracking+Cookie; Max-Age=1800;'.  That gives me something to investigate further - thank you!

Comment: Both Struts1 and Struts2 apps are deployed into the same AS which is a Sun Application Server 9.1 installation.

Comment: I should also add that the pages in both the Struts1 or Struts2 are not going to specific Actions that we have created (so no type= in Struts1 or class= in Struts2 in the struts config files).  Not sure that makes any difference but thought I'd add that info.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9156010/1654265

Comment: Thanks for the link Andrea.  We have now resolved the issue by using ProxyPassReverseCookiePath in Apache.